# Filter GridView with Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm displaying some data in the Grid View and it all works fine. However, I'm trying to include a Text-field with a search button for the user to be able to filter the data by Name (which is the first column of the table). So for example the user would input "James" and then only entries with the name James are displayed. 
This is my code:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Filter" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>


       <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Name" >
            <HeaderStyle Width="450px" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Height="100px" Width="400px" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Title" >
                <ItemStyle Width="400px" HorizontalAlign="Center" Height="100px" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
                </asp:BoundField>

        </Columns>

        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#002d57" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#002756" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <RowStyle ForeColor="#002756" />

    </asp:GridView>
   <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetData" TypeName="Test"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

In the code behind I have tried something like this but it just still displayed all the results of the table, not the ones I was specifically searching for :

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ((DataTable)GridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = "Name like '%" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "%' ";
    }
    catch (Exception) { }

}
```

Any suggestions how I can achieve this?

Comment: why not just set the `GridView1.RowFilter = string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%' , textBox1.Text);`

Comment: @MariaL : just a small thing : the try/catch in the Button1_Click hides all exceptions ... You should diplay or not hide them. Because it could the cause of your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// save your DataTable in session while binding gridview

// Session["Dt_GridView"]=Your_datatable;

And try following code

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["Dt_GridView"];
            dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Name like '%" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "%' ";
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }

    }
```

**Update**

As you are using ObjectDataSource you can directly call FilterExpression method as shown below

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (TextBox1.Text != "")
            {

                ObjectDataSource1.FilterExpression = "Name LIKE '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%'";

            }

        }
```

Comment: Yeah I tried this, but still nothing happening. It's probably some tiny thing that I'm overlooking

Comment: Thanks for the update- only issue is that the Select Method returns a List<T> so it won't work

Comment: If you are using List<T> then use LinqDataSource

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like this also

```
DataView dv = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView;
dv.RowFilter = "Name LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
dv.DataBind();
```

Comment: I get this error: System.Data.DataView' does not contain a definition for 'DataBind' and no extension method 'DataBind' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataView' could be found

Comment: Check your `using declaration in your header` `using System.Data`

Comment: the using declaration is all fine, which is confusing

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
((DataTable)GridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter.Contains(textBox1.Text);
```

Comment: Doesn't work sorry, it still displays the whole table not the results I search for